# Installing Intel AX200 Drivers With No Connection

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

On one of my Ubuntu 24.03 Desktop installs that is in a very rural area with no neighbors or other means of connecting to the Internet other than WiFi, can I pre-install the Intel AX200 drivers before removing the old Broadcom device and replacing it with the Intel device? How is it done?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 24.03. Please clarify: https://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: This should be supported on version 20.04 and newer. Many users are saying that [you need to disable fast startup in BIOS, and boot Windows 10, then restart, enter Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/mixxen/339846df6f316416336d038090a3c848#gistcomment-4064321-permalink).

Comment: If you have Ubuntu using kernel 6.5, check `uname -r` there should be no issue with an Intel wifi device

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. It’s 23.10. As I always keep my systems up to date and I was thinking it’s April, I presumed I had upgraded it.

Comment: As @Jeremy31 said, in kernel versions 6.5 and newer, it should just work with no further intervention.

Comment: Doesn't it need drivers? Nothing happened when I booted up and no WiFi device was found so I expected it was because the drivers were not installed which is what prompted my question about how to install them without a connection. By the way, I saw the comments about fast startup but I am not running a dual boot system so no Windows involved and this is also a relatively fresh install.

Comment: The required driver, *iwlwifi*, and the needed firmware are included by default. Please boot up and let us see, from the terminal: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`